# Dial up networking server?

Tags: networking

I want to network computer 1 and 2 using a phone line.

[image: Computer 1 and 2 are in different places.]

Computer 1 is connected a network, computer 2 wants to access that network in some capacity using a phone line.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Do you just want to access the LAN or also the Internet?

Comment: What are you planning to do with that network connection? You're barely going to be able to view files on the remote network, much less download or open files.

Comment: Really nice diagram! +1

Comment: I looked at the diagram for a good 30 seconds before realizing the things in the middle are telephone poles.  Excellent job my friend.  You should really reconsider this adventure.  Unless you have a specific text based application to use remotely, you're not going to be able to do much with your 0.056mbps.

Comment: You can probably do things like ssh, and ftp. Have a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto

Comment: Historically, there were gadgets called "modem"s (from "Modulate/Demodulate) that were used for just this purpose. Also investigate the OSI 7 level model at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: I remember being so happy with my 28.8kbps modem and how fast it was! There has got to be a way, because this was a built-in feature that I used to use in Windows 95! Also love that drawing.

Comment: Heres a question that looks similar, http://superuser.com/questions/676364/how-to-setup-a-network-between-two-machines-via-rj11-modular-telephone-cable. HTH

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Ubuntu??

Answer (score 1):

If the line between the two computers is a "dry line" as in no dial tone. You can use the following product: https://www.blackbox.com/en-us/store/Detail.aspx/Industrial-Ethernet-Extender---10-100-1-Port/LB320A

Which is called VDSL and can extend several miles at fairly good speeds, over normal single pair phone lines.

Comment: I use one of these: Planet VC-231 ( http://www.planet.com.tw/en/product/product.php?id=26560#appl )  Look at the diagram, it basically what he wants.
I use one as a "vDSL converter" instead of being dependant on a crappy telco-provided router. 

Using two, on a dry line should work